# error: invalid preprocessing token

Tags: c++11

```
#define A(a)  "str" ## a ## test
A(_)
```

According to `17.6.4.3.5` in C++11 standard

> Literal suffix identifiers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.

the above code should produce `"str"_test` which is a **valid** preprocessing token and it's class `user-defined-string-literal`.

clang 3.0 produce error when running in preprocessor mode via `-E`.

clang gives:

```
pasting formed '"str"_', an invalid preprocessing token
A(_)
^
note: expanded from:
#define A(a)  "str" ## a ## test
                    ^

"str"_test
1 error generated.
```

i don't understand what steps made it decide that the result is not a invalid preprocessing token.

Note: I'm writing a c++11 preprocessor.

Comment: why do you feel the need to use macros in c++, also I don't think `"` is legal in identifiers

Comment: You need to use the `-std=c++11` flag, with that, both, my g++ and my clang++ are happy with it, without it, both complain.

Comment: I use `clang++ -std=c++11 -E a.cpp` and it still produce the error.

Comment: Aha, then that seems to be a bug in clang++-3.0, or its C++11 support was only partial. 3.2 recognizes it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know how you compiled this `"` is not valid in indentifiers

Comment: @aaronman Sure, but there is no identifier involved here, just pasting some preprocessing tokens. And of course that won't _compile_, but you can run it through the preprocessor fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer when you use `##` you are attempting to make a token, which has to be a name of some sorts, therefore since you cannot have `"` in any sort of name it is illegal, what legal context could you even use this in

Comment: @aaronman: no using ## produce preprocessing token which is not a normal token because it has different rules, e.g. `1.3.2` is valid preprocessing token but not valid token.

Comment: @aaronman A string literal is a preprocessing token. I haven't checked, but it seems natural that a user-defined string literal is also a (valid) preprocessing token. And pasting the (valid) preprocessing tokens `"str"`, `_`, and `test` would then result in a valid preprocessing token.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, you keep saying it is a valid preprocessing but the compiler is saying it is not. If you want more help tell us what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: @aaronman: I'm afraid you're repeatedly missing the point. C++11 introduces user-defined literals, which makes `"str"_test` a valid token. He's probably getting errors because he's using an older compiler that doesn't support the new syntax.

Comment: What happens if you write `"str"_test` directly, without trying to construct it in the preprocessor?

Comment: i'm testing a case where concating a valid preprocessing token create a valid preprocessing token, my preprocessor is OK with it and g++ also but not clang++3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* the code is valid C++11; it looks like you're using a compiler with incomplete C++11 support.

Using g++ version 4.7.2 (with `-std=c++11`), this contrived program:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

#define A(a)  "str" ## a ## test

const char* operator"" _test(const char s[4], size_t size) {
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << A(_) << "\n";
}
```

compiles without error and produces this output:

```
str
```

clang++ version 3.0 is less happy; among other errors, it says:

```
c.cpp:11:18: error: pasting formed '"str"_', an invalid preprocessing token
    std::cout << A(_) << "\n";
                 ^
c.cpp:4:21: note: expanded from:
#define A(a)  "str" ## a ## test
                    ^
```

Comment: Well, is it bug in clang or it's because of a rule I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Muhammadalaa: I haven't been following clang development. It's probably just that that version of `clang` doesn't yet support user defined literals. If I write`"str"_test` directly, clang still complains. I wouldn't call it a "bug", just a missing or not-yet-implemented feature.